# Can I create a contractor login for my Firebase project?

Tags: firebase, firebase-console

I want to work with a remote contractor on my Firebase project, but I don't want to give my Google login credentials. Is there a way to create a separate "super-user" account so he can work on the project under another username? If not, anybody have suggestions on how to handle the situation?

Answer (score 2):

You can add him as a contributor/collaborator. This was slightly easier in the previous Firebase console, but can still be done.

### if your project is on firebase.google.com

1. Go to [www.console.firebase.google.com](http://www.console.firebase.google.com) and sign into your project
2. Click the gear icon ([image: this])
3. Click permissions
4. Make sure you are in the IAM tab, click "Add Member"
5. Type the email, select a role (most likely Project -> Editor)

**"Some roles are in beta development and might be changed or deprecated in the future."** ([reference](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles?hl=en_US#curated_roles))

### if your project is on firebase.com

1. Go to [www.firebase.com/account/](http://www.firebase.com/account/)
2. Click "Add Collaborator" at the bottom of one of your project cards ([image: this])
3. Type email, click invite

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Perhaps the problem I am really having is that the project that shows up in the console @ console.firebase.google.com

does NOT appear in my firebase.com page. Any ideas why that would be?

Thanks

Devin

Comment: So I discovered the fix to the issue I was having. I do NOT get the above options if I create the Firebase project in the console. I must create the project in firebase.com, and then it can be imported into the console, and collaborators can be invited.

Strange workflow - perhaps due to the migration process.

Answer (score 0):

You may first need to first 'import' your firebase.com project to the new firebase.google.com. In order to do this, navigate to the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/). Your firebase.com projects will show up here. Tap the 'Import' link and follow the steps. Once imported, follow @blindprohhets instructions to set up a collaborator.

Comment: I figured this out - please see above comment.